# Sum multiple cells in one sheet ("Sheet A") using sheet name in another sheet ("Summary")

Tags: excel

I have a sheet set up (summary sheet) to summarize values from several cells in another sheet (sheet 1, sheet 2, etc.) based on the name of the sheet in the summary sheet.
Example
I want to sum the values in the formula bar into BX2 based on the sheet name in BX1.

***Index1***
[image]

Comment: Use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: @BigBen I tried INDIRECT but it didn't seem to work with non-contiguous cells. Do you know how I would sum non-contiguous cells?

Comment: Use a separate instance of INDIRECT for each non-contiguous cell.